# Background Image Setting Equirectangular is missing

Tags: image, world

For some reason, a previous saved blender project managed to give me the Background image option called 'Equirectangular' to successfully show the image. However, having recently started another project, that option is no longer available to me. Now I can't display a background image. Here are some screenshots of the settings. First one is with the Equirectangular' option, and the second image is not giving me that. Instead it gives me an extra setting box.
[image: https://i.paste.pics/825f5ff366d5840395727c54f8a87b75.png]

[image: https://i.paste.pics/bd43acf5dc382f971ecfc73d759f6a77.png]

Comment: How did you add the image? These are the settings for an  _Image Texture_ , not an _Environment Texture_.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That was was the actual issue -- I chose Image Texture instead of Environment Texture. It's working now. Thanks again.